# Input Value to a Button onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The script is for a gambling game. User types in wager and number from 2,3,5,50. 
If the wheel spins , and the number on the wheel equals to the number , the user gets wager * number.

Example: User wagers 100 credits and bets on 2. Wheel spins and if it lands on 2 , User Gets 100*2 credits.

How do I change from typing 2,3,5,50 into a input, to a button "bet on 2" , " bet on 3 " , respectively.

Problem with my current: User enters every round as long as a valid wager and number is provided, when the wheel spins. Using a button, will allow the user to choose when he wants to bet( which is by clicking the button)

**Check this out:** http://codepen.io/hokaien/pen/RKjPbZ

```
if ( options[index] === wantTo ) {
// if options[index] equals to number
    var el = document.getElementById('number');
    var res = originalNumber += (amountBet * wantTo);
    el.textContent = res;
    finalMsg = " You won " + (amountBet * wantTo) + " credits";
  } else if (test3 != "2" || test3 != "3" || test3 != "5" || test3 != "50") {
    finalMsg = " Number should be from 2, 3, 5, 50 ";
  } else if (amountBet > originalNumber) {
    finalMsg = " Not enough credits ";
  } else if (amountBet < 0) {
    finalMsg = " Cannot bet negative ";
  }
```

Comment: You have multiple buttons?

Comment: You can check numeric values by jQuery.isNumeric()

Comment: Not check if it's a number, check if the button clicked  is equal to a number. @AmanKumar

Comment: there should be 4 buttons with 2,3,5,50 values .  @progrAmmar

Comment: @kaien ok, is it like the html I have in my answer?

Comment: does the options ever change? in other words do you want to generate the button dynamically using the "options" array, or just static buttons for this specific case?

Comment: There are only 4 options 2,3,5,50 to bet on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here you go (codepen)](http://codepen.io/Maher-Fa/pen/mRxjVB)

#### HTML added:

```
<input type='button' class='betButton' value="2"/>
<input type='button' class='betButton' value="3"/>
<input type='button' class='betButton' value="5"/>
<input type='button' class='betButton' value="50"/>
```

also removed the number input

#### JS added (jQuery):

this code handles clicks and sets the value of *currentBet*, it also adds a class called *selected* to the player's choice for clarity

```
$('.betButton').click(function() {
    currentBet = $(this).val();
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    $('.betButton').not(this).removeClass("selected");
});
```

#### JS Edits:

replaced refrences to the old number input and replaced it with *currrentBet*... afected variables are: *wantTo*, *test2* and *test3*

replaced the code that used to disable/enable input while spinning with

```
$( ".betButton" ).prop( "disabled", true )
```

and

```
$( ".betButton" ).prop( "disabled", false )
```

to disable and enable the bet buttons instead

#### CSS added:

```
input.betButton {
  border: none;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input.betButton:disabled {
 opacity: 0.4;
}
input.betButton.selected {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If using jQuery, you can use `.isNumeric()` to check for an input whether its number or not.

```
var result=$.isNumeric(txtInput.val());
```

Check for clicked buttons value

```
var result=$.isNumeric(btnClickedButton.val());
```

Or

```
$(".btnNumber2").click(function(){
    var result=$.isNumeric($(this).val());
    alert(result);
});
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**

**HTML**

```
<input type='button' class='myButton' value="bet on 2" data-val="2" />
<input type='button' class='myButton' value="bet on 3" data-val="3"  />
<input type='button' class='myButton' value="bet on 5" data-val="5"  />
<input type='button' class='myButton' value="bet on 50" data-val="50"  />
```

**JS**

```
var clickedScore=0;
$(".myButton").click(function(){
    var btn=$(this);
    clickedScore=btn.attr("data-val");
});

function CheckIfClickedButtonValueEqualsWheelNumber() //HAVE TO MAKE IT LONG
{
    if(parseInt(clickedScore)==YOUR_NUMBER_FROM_WHEEL){
    {
        //YOUR EXISTING LOGIC, NOT REPEATING IT HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: not check if it's a number, check if the button clicked is equal to a number

Comment: You can check for buttons value

Comment: I have tried updating my answer, please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

### Example

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
  var data = $(this).val();
  if(isNaN(data) == false)
   {
       alert('this is numeric');
   }
   else
   { 
     alert('Not a numbre');
   }
  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="btn" value="2" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text of the buttons

Suppose you have four buttons

```
<input type='button' class='myButton' value="2" />
<input type='button' class='myButton' value="3" />
<input type='button' class='myButton' value="5" />
<input type='button' class='myButton' value="50" />
```

You can easily check if the value is number or not

```
$('input.myButton').click(function(){
    var btn = $(this)
    var btnValue = btn.val();
    var isNum = $.isNumeric(btnValue);
});
```

If your button is defined as `<button type="button">[num]</button` Then you can get `btn.text()` in place of `btn.val()`.

Comment: It's not check the button value if it's a number. Its check if the number on the spinning wheel is equal to the button value clicked. So if user clicks "bet on 2" , the wheel spins and if the number on the wheel is equal to the button value "bet on 2" the user gets his wager * 2. please check out the code pen to see what i mean